# Criação das entidades e modelagem de domínio de Pessoa Física e Jurídica no padrão DDD CQRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ddd, cqrs

Estou criando uma aplicação do tipo ERP, e estou utilizando o Padrão DDD CQRS, onde no momento inicial do projeto estou criando as entidades de clientes, fornecedores e transportadoras, onde as mesmas herdam da entidade pessoa, pensei em fazer de diversas formas, mas não sei qual é a melhor para o padrão utilizado (DDD CQRS), gostaria de opiniões...

Sobre o sistema, ele será multi tenant,

Gostaria de dicas sobre o relacionamento do banco de dados e da modelagem do domínio, se tiverem exemplos de outros sistemas parecidos que utilizaram como padrão DDD CQRS ficarem grato.

abaixo segue um exemplo do protótipo da modelagem que estou pensando em fazer.
e abaixo dela a divisão das pastas dentro da camada "Domain".

[image: Modelagem de banco de dados Pessoa Física e Jurídica]

[image: Modelagem de domínio]

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso vc tem 3 Agregados TRANSPORTE, CLIENTE E FORNECEDOR

essas 3 entidades, cada uma e a Root do seu agregado, logo vc teria um Repositório para cada uma.

Eu eliminaria o sharedcontext pois cada AGREGATEROOT possui o seu repositório

Se vc tem a tabela Pessoa, o insert q será feito nela terá q partir do cliente, fornecedor e transportadora.

Por exemplo:. A classe clienterepository terá um método insert que vai receber o parâmetro ClienteEntity.  Ao chamar esse método internamente ele vai se virar para.gravar os dados de suas propriedades nas tabelas corretas q no seu caso, parece.q e cliente e pessoa